# integrate Google Photos with android system

Tags: google, photos

I use ios for long time recently switched to android. my whole photo library in google photos but when i need to upload somewhere  i need to download it first to device and proceed to upload its irritating is there any way to link google photos to gallery like ios icloud photos when i use ios i can select icloud photo directly and it download & upload automatically. why google can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive *was* the integrating factor till [July this year](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089). It was possible to sync photos with Drive. Drive also works with ios.

Now that it is discontinued, there is no automatic way to upload but from Photos settings you  enable sync to drive (tap on the cloud icon) or using the share option upload to third party cloud/messaging/mail options.